# How can I read or copy assets out of an .exe packaged with vercel/pkg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, assets, zeit-pkg

I have a [`pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)-packaged `.exe` I need to copy files out of - which I'm aware may not be possible - but surely there's some way to get the asset files out, right?

I'm quite confident that the assets are included in the `pkg` after I added this to my `package.json`:

```js
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "assets/**/*"
    ]
  },
```

and `--config package.json` to my `pkg` command.

But still, there doesn't seem to be any way to get files out of the executable besides, I guess, to store the files as strings and then write them to the disk (which seems, to me, madness.)

Is there some better way I'm overlooking? I guess Node's `fs` command can't read into the `.exe` in any way, but hopefully the `.exe` should be able to write the files out *somewhere, somehow?*

Does anyone know how?

**TLDR:** I'm looking to read, or ideally copy, assets out of the `.exe`

By the way: Vercel/pkg used to be known as Zeit/pkg

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with code like this:

```js
const isPackaged = process.pkg !== undefined; // process.pkg is only defined when packaged
const root = isPackaged ? 'C:\\snapshot\\your-package-name' : process.cwd();

export const ASSETS_PATH = path.join(root, 'assets');
```

At first I was hesitant to try this because I thought C:\snapshot may not be a reliable path if the user already had such a directory - and that some other path may be used - but that's not the case. C:\snapshot is virtual so there will never be a conflict with the real filesystem.